# Connect APEX account with Oracle Form Builder and SQL Devoloper

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Can I connect my apex account to Oracle Form Builder or SQL Developer?

I have Apex.oracle.com Account. Can I connect this account to my SQL Developer in local machine? and in Oracle Form Builder?

Answer (score 0):

An APEX account is very different from a database account.  The APEX account only allows you to access the APEX builder application.

You cannot connect to the database behind apex.oracle.com via SQL Developer or any other tool that relies on creating a database connection.  You can only connect to the APEX builder application via a web browser.

Oracle provides the express edition of the database (Oracle XE 11g) that you can download and run on your local machine free for whatever you'd like to do (including running commercial apps if you'd like).  If you are running a local database, you can create Oracle database accounts that you can access via SQL Developer as well as creating APEX accounts that you can access to develop APEX applications in the APEX builder.